# Prove the relations $A\cap B = \varnothing$ and $A\cap B^{c} = A$ are equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Show that the two statements are equivalent
$$ A \cap B = \emptyset$$
$$ A\setminus B = A $$

This is what I have done so far. Defined the first statement in terms of logical symbols

$$ \neg\exists x((x\in a)\land(x\in B))$$ Then I simplified further distributing the negation but I cannot get the second statement to look close at all. What am I missing

Comment: Is it required to use logical symbols? If not, you can simply notice that if the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is the empty set, there are no elements that are in both $A$ and $B$; as such, the set of elements in $A$ that are not in $B$ contains all of $A$'s elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't normally do this by manipulating statements using formal logical symbols, but it seems a little amusing right now.

\begin{align*}
&A\cap B = \emptyset \\
\iff& \forall x(x\in A\cap B \iff x\in\emptyset) \\
\iff& \forall x(x\in A\cap B \iff \text{false}) \\
\iff& \forall x(\neg(x\in A\cap B)) \\
\iff& \forall x(\neg(x\in A\wedge x\in B)) \\
\iff& \forall x(x\not\in A\vee x\not\in B)) \\
\iff& \forall x(x\in A \implies x\not\in B)) \\
\iff& \forall x(x\in A \implies(x \not\in B \iff \text{true})) \\
\iff& \forall x((x\in A \wedge x \not\in B) \iff (x\in A\wedge\text{true})) \\
\iff& \forall x((x\in A \wedge x \not\in B) \iff x\in A) \\
\iff& \forall x(x\in A\setminus B \iff x\in A)\\
\iff& A\setminus B = A
\end{align*}

This is, more or less, every single step, including expanding definitions and applying basic logical lemmas.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what did you do after A implies not B. The two steps where you had "true" confuse me

Comment: It turns out that $p\implies (q\iff r)$ is equivalent to $(p\wedge q)\iff (p\wedge r)$.  If $r$ is "true", then this reduces to the statement $p \implies q$ being equivalent to $(p\wedge q)\iff p$.

Comment: I came up with this by simultaneously working forwards and backwards, and introducing this "true" into the statement was what helped me make the statements meet in the middle.

Comment: Thats very clever. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove the direction ($\Leftarrow$) first:

\begin{align*}
A\cap B & = (A\cap B^{c})\cap B\\\\
& = A\cap(B\cap B^{c})\\\\
& = A\cap\varnothing\\\\
& = \varnothing
\end{align*}

To prove the direction ($\Rightarrow$), if $A\cap B = \varnothing$, then we conclude that $A\subseteq B^{c}$.

Hence $A\cap B^{c} = A$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would like suggest representation
$$A = (A \cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)$$
Now if $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $A=A\setminus B$.

If $A=A\setminus B$, then $A \cap B = (A\setminus B)\cap B = \emptyset$.